# Jquery link with query parameter to ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have links like 
`http://example.com?query1=query1&query2=query2` as href of anchor tag. 
I want to do post ajax on href click using data from the query parameter from the link. 
I have written code

```
$("a").bind('click',function(){
    $.ajax({type:'post',url:$(this).attr('href'), success: function(data){
    alert(data);
  }})
        return false;
});
```

but it does not send query parameter inside ajax post request. Request query data length is 0.

how can I change this code to manipulate data from query parameter of link ?

**Edit**

Sorry my bad but it is not working these are the request

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0


Query String parameter 
action:delete
id:12
```

So these fields are not going inside request content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>You need to use the value of the href attribute, not just the jQuery object itself.</strike>

<strike>url:$(this).attr('href').val()</strike>

**Update**

Although you said this answer worked for you, I made a mistake. val is not a valid function of attr however doing it the original way you had it works for me.

See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PuyzU/

**Update 2**

Ok, I see your problem now. It wasn't atall clear from the question what you meant.

Let me rewrite your question here to make sure I'm on the right track.

> I want to take the querstring parameters of a URL and use them in my ajax
>   POST action. How do I do that with jQuery?

In your ajax post method there is a property `data` where you'll store the data you want to post to the server.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: "http://[...],
    data: DataToPostToServerHere
    [...]
```

In this case we can obtain the querysting parameter values as a single string by splitting our URL on the `?` and use the first portion of the array as the URL and the second portion as the data we're sending:

```
var urlFull = $('#myLink').attr('href').split('?');
urlFull[0] // Our URL
urlFull[1] // The data to put into the data property for posting.
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/PuyzU/1/)

Comment: Really? I just checked my code sample and I think it's wrong. Using .val() throws an error, infact doing it your original way works for me.

Comment: oh sorry not :P 
I was trying here http://jsfiddle.net/Sta7D/8/ 
and on click it was javascript error and page was loading it self with those value. 
I network panel I thought it is ajax request :P

Comment: Here's an updated and working version of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/Sta7D/10/

Comment: Notice also that I replaced your return false; with event.preventDefault(). This is a more desirable way (more jQuery way) to do what u want.

Comment: sorry it don't works :( these are going as
query string 
action:delete
id:12

Comment: @Vivek - I didn't understand your question but I think I may do now. See my second update please.